# How to prevent sending auto emails for specific actions in wordpress

Tags: email

How to prevent sending auto emails for specific actions in wordpress, i have a function that generate password for users, only after the admin accept the user application

```
create_user_password($subscription->ID),
//this function calls wp_update_user
```

Wordpress sends a message about a (password change action), how to prevent this ONLY if this method was triggered by an admin

Comment: [That is not a core WordPress method](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=create_user_password) - where is `create_user_password()` coming from?

Comment: it calls the wp_update_user method, sorry, i should mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in [the documentation of `wp_update_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/) you will see that it uses two filters:

- `send_password_change_email`
- `send_email_change_email`

Simply from the names I would guess if you return `false` in `send_password_change_email` it should work. So something along the lines of:

```
function create_user_password($id) {
    // other code
    add_filter('send_password_change_email', '__return_false');
    wp_update_user(...);
    remove_filter('send_password_change_email', '__return_false');
}
```